# High RU charge with case-insensitive search

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I have a Cosmos DB collection with 4 million documents (~5GB). The following query reports a charge of 2.79 RUs:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.type='type1' and STRINGEQUALS(c.name,'abc',false)
```

But the same query with case-insensitive search (by replacing `false` by `true`) costs **1228 RUs**.

Is there an explanation for why the case-insensitive query is more than 470 times more expensive than the case-sensitive query? I'm surprised by this because the [documentation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/new-string-function-performance-improvements-and-case-insensitive-search/) states

> The RU charge for StartsWith and StringEquals is slightly higher with the case-insensitive option than without it.

---

Details:

- Both queries return 0 results.
- The partition key is `type`.
- The logical partition `type1` contains 2 million documents.
- The `name` property has a different value for almost all 2 million documents.
- The default indexing strategy is used (`"path": "/*"`)

Comment: Could be that the emulator does not have all of the optimizations that Cosmos added over time. When I query this over a collection of 100,000 I get almost equal RU usage (2,79 vs 2,80). I would expect a significant difference even with only 100,000 documents. So I think the RU from the emulator is not a good representation in this case.

Comment: @404 I also had almost identical RU charges on the Emulator with smaller collections (a few thousand docs). I had hoped I could measure the charge for various queries in with various different data collections on the Emulator to save time and money. :-(

Comment: @404 I can now confirm that the same behavior is exhibited in a "real" Cosmos DB collection. 2.79 RUs for case-sensitive and 1228.01 RUs for case-insensitive search.

Comment: @404 I suspect that you observe no difference in RU consumption because either the first criterion `c.type = 'type1'` restricts the number of possible results to a small number or the cardinality of `c.name` is much smaller in your collection.

Comment: I tested without the `c.type` expression so the query ran over my entire collection filtering on a MD5 hash. Upon trying the same with a new database with 12 million documents the performance gets even worse than your results with 569604 RU. I'm quite surprised about that outcome considering my 100k collection barely showed a difference. Adding an `order by c.md5` to force an index scan lowers it to 7700 RU

Comment: @404 I wonder why Cosmos DB can't automatically add an `order by` clause to the execution plan if it helps with performance. But even "only" 7700 RU indicates that a linear index scan is performed rather than a constant-time lookup as in the case-sensitive case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I found out so far:

#### Does Cosmos DB support efficient case-insensitive string comparison?

Unfortunately, the RU charge for case-insensitive `STRINGEQUALS` seems to be **linear** in the cardinality of the property (i.e. the number of different values for that property). Which is really, really bad if you have lots of documents. The query above takes almost 1 s at a throughput of 10,000 RU/s. In contrast, *case-sensitive* string comparison is independent of the size of the collection. See also [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/273498/cosmos-db-case-insensitive-search-consumes-lots-of.html) discussion.

#### What if I need efficient case-insensitive string comparisons?

For small collections (< 10,000 docs) case-sensitivity doesn't make that much of a difference. (And also of course if the inclusion of the partition key restricted the size of the potential result set to a much smaller number.)

For larger collections you could store a duplicate of each property that should support efficient case-insensitive search in lower case and do a case-sensitive search on the lower-case property instead.

You can vote for the Feature Request to support efficient case-insensitive queries [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/42727268-efficient-case-insensitive-search).